# http gives responce just once

Tags: flutter, http, hardware

this code gives me response just in the first time I send request. then it doesn't give any response no matter how many times i send the request.
I'm using Tenda router with Sonoff device.

I tried to post request in postman and everything works fine.

```
 import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void sendRequest() async {
    print('first');

    var client = http.Client();
    try {
      print('before send');
      var response = await client
          .post(Uri.http('192.168.1.2:8081', 'zeroconf/monitor'),
          body: {"deviceid": "10016b7046", "data": {"subDevId": "3d18474c3831311947313130", "outlet": 3, "time": 180}});
      print('after');

      var decoderes = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;
      print('after send1');

      var url = Uri.parse(decoderes['url'] as String);
      print('after send33');

      print(await client.get(url));
    } finally {
      print('after send');
      client.close();
    }
    print('after send2');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('request'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            sendRequest();
          },
          child: const Text('request'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the postman response:

```
{
   "seq": 9,
   "error": 0
}
```

[image: my post request on postman]

[image: and those the headers I'm using]

Comment: Which of your print statements get printed?

Comment: only "first" get printed.

Comment: Your post body is invalid. If you supply a map, it must be a `Map<String, String>`. Were you perhaps meant to JSON encode it? What does your Postman request look like - update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: I updated the question as you asked. actually the SonOff http documentation says that the body should be this way in the http request.

Comment: Postman shows a JSON encoded body of the post - not form values as you are trying to do. Change your code to `body: json.encode({'deviceid': ...`

Comment: I've tried to encode the body as you mention it. didn't work. I made the same request in visual basic, it works fine. Does it have anything to do with flutter?

Comment: Since you are using HTTP (vs HTTPS) use wireshark to capture an interaction at the server end. This should allow easy comparison of a working vs non-working request

Comment: Did you ate least see more print statements? Update the question to show the new code.

Comment: Also, do you see how Postman has given you some 'equivalent' Dart code on the right. Try pasting that into a plain Dart command line project and try that.

Comment: I did use the code that Postman provided. didn't work neither. I'm gonna try to use what you've mentioned earlier and update you if I come up with something. thanks for taking the time to help me.